# How does git decide which version of svn to use in git-svn?

Tags: git, path, git-svn, homebrew

I have installed `git` and `svn` with homebrew on my mac running 10.7.4. There is a version of `svn` on my machine in `/usr/bin` which appears to be the version that `git svn` is using.

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.4

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.7.5 (r1336830)

$ git svn --version
git-svn version 1.7.10.4 (svn 1.6.17)

$ /usr/bin/svn --version
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
```

So, can I change the version of svn that git-svn uses? If so, how do I go about it?

Thanks for reading.

--Updated for comment--

```
$ which git svn
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/svn

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: What is the output of `which svn`, and what's in your `PATH`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a little digging, and it looks like git-svn uses subversion's perl bindings.  After a little experimentation, I found that installing an upgraded version of svn *with perl enabled* fixed the problem.  On Mac OSX, this would go something like this:

```
# First, I had to take ownership of the perl libs dir,
# so homebrew could create perl modules
chown $USER -R /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level

# Then, remove and reinstall Subversion, but add the perl option:
brew remove svn
brew install --perl svn

# Lastly, reinstall git (this may be optional, but it may also help.)
brew remove git
brew install git
```

Your problem boils down to the simple fact that your updated Subversion installation didn't include the accompanying perl modules, so git-svn was falling back on the more complete system installation.

For the record, symlinking /usr/bin/svn to /usr/local/bin/svn did absolutely no good.  This has nothing to do with `$PATH` or anything else, and everything to do with perl modules.

Comment: I tried your solution and git svn --version still refer to the System svn version so I rename the `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level\SVN` to `SVN-old` and `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level\auto\SVN` to `SVN-old` (use `sudo`) and replace it with symlink from `/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.8/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/SVN` and `/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.8/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/SVN` respectively

Answer (score 1):

Your system has two versions of Subversion installed: 1.6.17 in `/usr/bin/svn`, and 1.7.5 in `/usr/local/bin/svn`. When you run `svn`, it parses your `$PATH` correctly to pick up the one in `/usr/local/bin/svn`, but `git-svn` doesn't bother, and just uses the version in `/usr/bin`.

Having had a quick glance through the code, there's nothing in `git-svn.pl` or Alien-SVN (the Perl Subversion library that `git-svn` uses) that explicitly points to any particular `svn` binary, so I suspect it's a security "feature" to avoid looking at your custom `$PATH`.

The easy option, if you have access, is to replace `/usr/bin/svn` with `/usr/local/bin/svn`; possibly by deleting and replacing with a symlink. Otherwise, I suspect you'll need to dig into the source of `git-svn.pl` and rewrite it to accept your custom `$PATH`.

Comment: I tried the symlinking idea, it did not work, git-svn still managed to use svn 1.6.17, which really doesn't make sense to me.  I wish I knew how to uninstall that version of svn completely.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that reach here with the same problem:
Now GIT has an option to use the Homebrew's version of SVN:

```
brew install --with-brewed-svn git
```

Hope this help (I dug long time before finding it!)